# Convergence of $f(x)+ f^{2} (x) + f^{3}(x)+ … $

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Imagine that $x \in (0,1]$ and $f$ is a continuous function such that $0 <f(x) < x$. Also, for any $k \in \mathbf N$ define $f^{k}(x)$ recursively by $f^{k} (x) = f(f^{k-1} (x))$.

Are there any theorems that put simple, but also fairly general conditions on $f(x)$ that ensures that the series $f(x)+ f^{2} (x) + f^{3}(x)+ …$ is convergent? Thanks.

Comment: Applying the condition for $x=0$ we find that $f(0) < 0$, so the range of $f$ must be allowed to include negative numbers. If so, then ANY continuous function on $[0,1]$ that only takes negative values will satisfy your requirement, and there is no reason for your series to converge. (For example, the function may be CONSTANT, taking the value $-1$ for all $x$.) My main point is that the question, as stated right now, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to assume that $f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ and $f(x)<x$ for any $x>0$?

Comment: Are you after $f'(0)<1$ with some conditions?

Comment: You are free to assume something to have the question make sense: for example, what Eric Wofsey said could be a possibility. The core of my question is finding a way of tackling such a problem.

Answer (score 4):

A condition for the convergence of the *sequence* $\{f^k(x)\}$ is that $f$ is a contraction: if there exists a number $0 \le \theta < 1$ with the property that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \theta |x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$, it is fairly routine to show that $\{f^k(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence for any $x$ in the domain of $f$, and moreover that the limit is the same for all $x$.

This suggests an analogy for series.

If there is a constant $0 \le \theta < 1$ with the property that $0 < f(x) \le \theta x$ for all $x$, then $f: (0,1] \to (0,\theta]$ and by iterating the inequality you find $0 \le f^k(x) \le \theta^{k-1}x \le \theta^{k-1}$ for all $x$. The series is then seen to be convergent using the comparison test with a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Thanks Umberto P. . This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Umberto's answer is a consequence of the ratio test. In fact, if $\limsup_n \frac{f^{n+1}(x)}{f^n(x)} < 1$, then your series converges. This is surely satisfied if  $\limsup_x \frac{f(x)}{x} < 1$. An alternative is to apply the root test ($\limsup_n f^n(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1$). A priori we know that both $\limsup$'s are $\le 1 =$ borderline between convergence and divergence.